# omiting path from url

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

I'm newbie in Django Channels and I'm trying to follow and recreate this project from Django channels documentation (which is 4 part) :
https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_1.html#add-the-index-view 
as you can see for accessing the project I have to go with STH like this: 192.168.43.175:8000/chat/lobby_room
I'm wondering how to completely omit the path and accessing the project through : 192.168.43.175:8000/

This is my **urls.py** :

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('chat/', include('chat.urls')),
]
```

This is my **views.py** :

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'chat/index.html')

def room(request, room_name):
    return render(request, 'chat/room.html', {
        'room_name': room_name
    })
```

This is my *chat* application **urls.py**:

```py
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<str:room_name>/', views.room, name='room'),
]
```

This is my **routing.py**:

```py
from django.urls import re_path

from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/chat/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$', consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

This is my **consumers.py**:

```py
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer

class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name

        # Join room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    # Receive message from WebSocket
    async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        # Send message to room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': message
            }
        )

    # Receive message from room group
    async def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']

        # Send message to WebSocket
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer

class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name

        # Join room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    # Receive message from WebSocket
    async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        # Send message to room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': message
            }
        )

    # Receive message from room group
    async def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']

        # Send message to WebSocket
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))
```

This is my **room.html**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Chat Room</title>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="chat-log" cols="100" rows="20"></textarea><br>
    <input id="chat-message-input" type="text" size="100"><br>
    <input id="chat-message-submit" type="button" value="Send">
    {{ room_name|json_script:"room-name" }}
    <script>
        const roomName = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('room-name').textContent);

        const chatSocket = new WebSocket(
            'ws://'
            + window.location.host
            + '/ws/chat/'
            + roomName
            + '/'
        );

        chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
            const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
            document.querySelector('#chat-log').value += (data.message + '\n');
        };

        chatSocket.onclose = function(e) {
            console.error('Chat socket closed unexpectedly');
        };

        document.querySelector('#chat-message-input').focus();
        document.querySelector('#chat-message-input').onkeyup = function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {  // enter, return
                document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').click();
            }
        };

        document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').onclick = function(e) {
            const messageInputDom = document.querySelector('#chat-message-input');
            const message = messageInputDom.value;
            chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
                'message': message
            }));
            messageInputDom.value = '';
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to fix this issue :)

Step 1 :

In **views.py** :
We have to replace this code :

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'chat/room.html', {
        'room_name': 'lobby_room'
    })
```

Step2:

In *chat* applications **urls.py** :
replace this code :

```py
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Step3:

Finally, replace this code in **urls.py** :

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('chat.urls')),
]
```

That's it :)

Answer (score 0):

Url paths are defined in urls.py file in django. As you can see in your urls.py file you have added the chat app on `chat/` path which means the app will be accessed at `192.168.43.175:8000/chat/`.
So to serve the chat app to `192.168.43.175:8000/` url you simply need to replace `chat/` with `/` in your urls.py like this

```
path('', include('chat.urls'))
```

Comment: if it answers your question use the tick button to accept the answer

Comment: yes bro that's right but I want to have **lobby_room** in my `192.168.43.175:8000/`, actually i want delete **chat** and replace it with **lobby_room** .                @blaze2004

Comment: is lobby_room the room name

Comment: as you can see you are serving index.html at `192.168.43.175:8000/` so  you need to  move `index.html` to  some other url and then you can serve lobby_room at `192.168.43.175:8000/`. You need to  change your chat app urls.py.

Comment: But in your case you can't do that as you are passing the room name i.e lobby_room in the url to identify the room. if you still want to do, then you need to  pass room name through http requests.